# How to find a sequence of bytes on the target program from my injected dll?

Tags: c++, dll, reverse-engineering, ida, cheat-engine

I'm developing a DLL that is injected into a process and uses some memory addresses. My idea is that my DLL finds and updates those addresses automatically, as I have the patterns and I can find them perfectly in IDA with **Search -> Sequence of bytes...**

[image]

As you can see it finds the sequence of bytes with wildcards

[image]

Now, I'm trying to replicate this IDA functionality in my DLL.

What I've tried so far in my code is the following:

```
uintptr_t mainModule = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI MainFunc(HMODULE hModule) {
    AllocConsole();
    FILE* f;
    freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

    mainModule = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"client.dll");
    if (hModule)
    {
        if (GetPatterns()) while (true) Sleep(1);    
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Main module not found, press ENTER to exit..." << std::endl;
        getchar();
    }

    fclose(f);
    FreeConsole();
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hModule, 0);
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MainFunc, hModule, 0, nullptr));
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

bool Compare(const BYTE* pData, const BYTE* pMask, const char* pszMask) {
    for (; *pszMask; ++pszMask, ++pData, ++pMask) {
        if (*pszMask == 'x' && *pData != *pMask) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (*pszMask) == NULL;
}

uintptr_t FindPattern(uintptr_t dwAddress, DWORD dwLen, BYTE* bMask, const char* szMask) {
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwLen; i++)
        if (Compare((BYTE*)(dwAddress + i), bMask, szMask))
            return (uintptr_t)(dwAddress + i);
    return 0;
}

MODULEINFO mInfo;
bool GetPattern(BYTE pattern[], const char* mask)
{
    DWORD foundAddress = FindPattern(mainModule, mInfo.SizeOfImage, pattern, mask);

    if (foundAddress != 0) {
        std::cout << "Found pattern at: 0x" << std::hex << foundAddress << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Error: pattern not found" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

bool GetPatterns()
{
    if (GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), (HMODULE)mainModule, &mInfo, sizeof(mInfo))) {
        BYTE pattern[] = { 0x48, 0x8B, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x85, 0xC0, 0x74, 0x00, 0x8B, 0x88 };
        const char* mask = "xxx????xxxx?xx";
        if (!GetPattern(pattern, mask)) return false;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error: unable to get module info" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And I'm getting an address as output **Found pattern at: 0xcae401b0** that takes to nowhere:

[image]

(Trying client.dll + the output address but also takes to nowhere)

Comment: Read [General Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices#general-best-practices) for DllMain.  You should not call CreateThread in DllMain.  It can work but is risky.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

Changing this line:

```
DWORD foundAddress = FindPattern(mainModule, mInfo.SizeOfImage, pattern, mask);
```

To this:

```
uintptr_t foundAddress = FindPattern(mainModule, mInfo.SizeOfImage, pattern, mask);
```